# controller and ingress shim errors

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, cert-manager

I am trying to get this to work on GKE, but with no luck unfortunately, and I cannot seem to figure out why. I'm using websockets and everything works as it should, DNS points to the correct IP, but the problem is that I can not get wss / ssl to work.

My architecture consists of a LoadBalancer service, and a simple ubuntu pod with nodejs server. I added an additional pod service for every pod. Here are the configs:
**LB**

```
yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: myapp-lb
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  loadBalancerIP: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
  ports:
  - port: 443
    name: https
  - port: 80
    name: http
  selector:
    app: myapp-svc
```

**Service**

```
yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: myapp-svc
  labels:
    app: myapp
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
  - name: https
    port: 443
    targetPort: 443 
  - name: rtsp
    port: 554
    targetPort: 554   
  selector:
    app: myapp
```

**App**

```
yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: myapp
  labels:
    app: myapp
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: myapp
        app: myapp
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60
      containers:
      - image: gcr.io/xx-xx-124315/myapp:210ac195d-dirty
        name: myapp
        ports:
        - containerPort: 443
          hostPort: 443
        - containerPort: 80
          hostPort: 80
        - containerPort: 554
          hostPort: 554
        env:
          - name: POD_NAME
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                fieldPath: metadata.name
          - name: POD_NAMESPACE
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        volumeMounts:
          - name: certdata
            mountPath: "/etc/certdata"
            readOnly: true        
        securityContext:
          capabilities:
              add:
              - ALL
      volumes:
        - name: certdata
          secret:
              secretName: myapp-tls
```

I mounted a volume with the value of "myapp-tls" as creating a wss server requires .key & .cert files (`https.createServer({key: fs.readFileSync('keys/server.key'), cert: fs.readFileSync('keys/server.crt')}, this.app)`)

I Installed cert-manager in default ns using static yamls.
**crd**

```
yaml
apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
metadata:
  name: certificates.certmanager.k8s.io
  labels:
    app: cert-manager
spec:
  group: certmanager.k8s.io
  version: v1alpha1
  scope: Namespaced
  names:
    kind: Certificate
    plural: certificates
    shortnames:
```

### - certs

```
apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
metadata:
  name: clusterissuers.certmanager.k8s.io
  labels:
    app: cert-manager
spec:
  group: certmanager.k8s.io
  version: v1alpha1
  scope: Cluster
  names:
    kind: ClusterIssuer
    plural: clusterissuers
```

---

```
apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
metadata:
  name: issuers.certmanager.k8s.io
  labels:
    app: cert-manager
spec:
  group: certmanager.k8s.io
  version: v1alpha1
  scope: Namespaced
  names:
    kind: Issuer
    plural: issuers
```

**deployment**

```
yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: cert-manager
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: cert-manager
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: cert-manager
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: cert-manager
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: default
      containers:
      - name: mgr
        image: quay.io/jetstack/cert-manager-controller:v0.2.3
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        args:
          - --cluster-resource-namespace=$(POD_NAMESPACE)
        env:
        - name: POD_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 10m
            memory: 32Mi
      - name: shim
        image: quay.io/jetstack/cert-manager-ingress-shim:v0.2.3
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        args:
          - --default-issuer-name=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/ca-issuer
          - --default-issuer-kind=ClusterIssuer
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 10m
            memory: 32Mi
```

I created a **secret** for letsencrypt

```
- openssl genrsa -out ca.key 2048
- openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key ca.key -subj "/CN=${myapp-tls}" -days 3650 -
˓→reqexts v3_req -extensions v3_ca -out ca.crt
```

added it to my **clusterIssuer**

```
yaml
apiVersion: certmanager.k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: ca-issuer
  namespace: default
spec:
  acme:
    server: https://acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    email: ssl-certificate@mydomain.com
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name:  ca-key-pair
    http01: {}
```

and created a **Certificate**

```
yaml
apiVersion: certmanager.k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: myapp
  namespace: default
spec:
  secretName: myapp-tls
  issuerRef:
    name: ca-issuer
    kind: ClusterIssuer
  commonName: sub.myapp.com
  dnsNames:
  - sub.myapp.com
  acme:
    config:
    - http01:
        ingressClass: nginx
      domains:
      - sub.myapp.com
```

Now if I log the `cert-manager mgr` pod, I get this output every 20mins:

```
09:46:03.159052       1 sync.go:242] Error preparing issuer for certificate: error waiting for key to be available for domain "sub.myapp.com": context deadline exceeded
E1115 09:46:03.169486       1 sync.go:190] [default/myapp] Error getting certificate 'camera-streaming-service-tls': secret "myapp-tls" not found
E1115 09:46:03.172931       1 controller.go:196] certificates controller: Re-queuing item "default/myapp" due to error processing: error waiting for key to be available for domain "sub.myapp.com": context deadline exceeded
I1115 09:46:03.172995       1 controller.go:187] certificates controller: syncing item 'default/myapp
I1115 09:46:03.181199       1 sync.go:107] Error checking existing TLS certificate: secret "myapp-tls" not found
I1115 09:46:03.181254       1 sync.go:238] Preparing certificate with issuer
I1115 09:46:03.207899       1 prepare.go:239] Compare "" with "https://acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/reg/45778309"
`

Same goes every 20mins for **cert-manager ingress-shim** pod:
`1 controller.go:147] ingress-shim controller: syncing item 'default/cm-myapp-ugvem'
E1115 09:46:03.135397       1 controller.go:177] ingress 'default/cm-myapp-ugvem' in work queue no longer exists
I1115 09:46:03.135410       1 controller.go:161] ingress-shim controller: Finished processing work item "default/cm-myapp-ugvem"
I1115 09:46:04.058887       1 controller.go:147] ingress-shim controller: syncing item 'default/cm-myapp-zoulq'
I1115 09:46:04.059135       1 sync.go:41] Not syncing ingress default/cm-myapp-zoulq as it does not contain necessary annotations
I1115 09:46:04.059248       1 controller.go:161] ingress-shim controller: Finished processing work item "default/cm-myapp-zoulq"
`

I noticed that every 20mins a new ingress, service, and pod get created, namely:
ingress` cm-myapp-zoulq   sub.myapp.com    80        11m`
svc` cm-myapp-kvzup   NodePort       10.39.242.227   <none>           8089:31006/TCP               11m`
pod` cm-myapp-bbeda   1/1       Running   0          10m`

Afaik i should be getting a myapp-tls secret with .key and .ca so i can add those to my nodejs server setup, and once i fix those errors on ingress-shim and mngr, everything should work.
I can not figure out what seems to be the problem, please help, and tnx.

**Environment details:**:
- Kubernetes version (e.g. v1.10.2):
kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"9", GitVersion:"v1.9.7", GitCommit:"dd5e1a2978fd0b97d9b78e1564398aeea7e7fe92", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-04-19T00:05:56Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"9+", GitVersion:"v1.9.7-gke.7", GitCommit:"9b635efce81582e1da13b35a7aa539c0ccb32987", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-11-02T23:07:38Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.3b4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

- Cloud-provider/provisioner (e.g. GKE, kops AWS, etc): GKE

/kind bug
```

Comment: Looking at the error, it seems like its unable to find the secret. Hence, what command did you run to create the secret? If you unsure if the secret was created, you can run `kubectl get secret` to make sure that indeed a secret does exist. If no secret was found; then you would need to create it using `kubectl create secret`.

Comment: Please update the question